# aws EMR unable to add rules to security groups dynamically?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr

I am following the aws documentation and created 3 security groups needed.

1. master
2. core
3. task

Now I am creating the cluster and it fails saying

**Terminated with errorsAmazon EC2 permissions error when configuring required rules on securityGroup XXXXX.**

What IAM permissions or other permissions I need to achieve this ?

Also how does a AWS service adds rules to the SG dynamically ? What permission does it need to achieve this ? Can it be more restrictive like the IAM roles/resources access?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the service needs to modify security group rules, it must have the following permissions for the respective security groups:

```
"Effect": "Allow",
"Actions": [
    "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups",
    "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupEgress",
    "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress",
    "ec2:RevokeSecurityGroupEgress",
    "ec2:RevokeSecurityGroupIngress"
],
"Resources": [
    "1st-security-group-arn",
    "2nd-security-group-arn",
    ...
]
```

Note: Depending on what you're trying to do, it might also need `"ec2:CreateSecurityGroup"` and `"ec2:DeleteSecurityGroup"`.

You can find the default permissions for the Amazon EMR Service Role in the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-iam-role.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was exactly what I was missing in my IAM role